# Where do I found multiple choice questions dataset?

Tags: training, transformer, datasets, training-datasets

I'm trying to train a GPT model to generate multiple choice questions about programming language, but I couldn't find any suitable dataset that contains mcq with answer about any programming language like c++, java, etc.., I searched in all the dataset websites but found nothing, how to I found one?